# Firebase - how to hide the token using frontend JS. How secure is it

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am developing a web ap with firebase and I want to connect it directly from the frontend using JS so I avoid to have a middle layer. So my question is basically how can I do a secure implementation with firebase and how can I hide the credentials that will be exposed on Javascript

Comment: What middle layer are you referring to?  I never heard of firebase before but it seems like they host everything and they handle all security related things for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never store credentials on the client. See this overview for a quick summary of how security works in Firebase: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html

If you don't want to run your own server to do authentication, you can use the Firebase Simple Login service. Simple Login integrates with Facebook, Github, Twitter and Persona to provide user login. You can learn more about the service and how to use it here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html