# How to make firebase database connection secure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new with firebase. I am not sure how to secure db-connect scripts. If i check source code in browser i can see everything i need to access my firebase database.

For example i can see this:

```
var db = new Firebase('https://urlToDb/emails');

db.push({addr:$scope.emailAddress, randomId: $scope.id, ip-addr:
$scope.ipAddress, friends:[{email:'test',ip:'10.20.40.123'}] })
```

Also you can see all the initialize code:

```
// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
  apiKey: "key",
  authDomain: "domain",
  databaseURL: "url",
  storageBucket: "storagebucket",
  messagingSenderId: "id"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

Is here all the code that user needs if he want's to get access my database? If i am right user needs only copy these codes and run them on his own server. Do i have to make some kind of server side script to hide these or is there some other ways to do this?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540695/firebase-how-to-hide-the-token-using-frontend-js-how-secure-is-it